# How to set the <title> dynamically in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, title, page-title

while launching a jsp page, I want to display the 'edition type' at the top of the browser window/ tab if page launched in 'teacher edition type'. There are 3 types of editions available in DB table, these are - teacher, student & common.
In my JSP code, I am trying to set  & trying to fetch 'edition type' from java action class. but, unable to do so.

Can anyone please guide how to get the Edition type in a JSP page

JSP code -

```
<% String printEditionTyp = (String)request.getAttribute("bookEditionID"); %>

<title>Message - <%out.print(printEditionTyp); %></title>

    }
```

Comment: Did you try `<%= printEditionTyp %>`?

Comment: I tried code as I mentioned above, it gives null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are providing page-tile in header tag of html i.e. inside `<head>` tag.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <% Long printEditionTyp = (Long) request.getAttribute("bookEditionID"); %>
        <title>Message - <%= printEditionTyp %></title>
    </head>
<body>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: Typecasted `bookEditionID` to `Long` in place of `String`

Comment: Yes, it's at the same place only. I noticed, in java action class bookEditionID is of Long type. Can you suggest what to use in jsp file

Comment: If `printEditionTyp` is having `null` value then you must check the code where you have set the attribute "bookEditionID" and also check that your JSP page is invoked/called by `requestDispatcher.forward(req,resp)` and NOT by `response.sendRedirect()`.

Comment: ..Now, I have set the attribute "bookEditionID" in my java class. This "bookEditionID" is of Long type in java class. Please guide how to use this Long type in JSP file. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer since `bookEditionID` is a `Long` value and you can use as shown in example.